# Issue with .htaccess redirecting all pages to HTTPS except one

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have the code below in my .htaccess to redirect all pages to https except one (/wc-api/v2), which must NOT use SSL.

It does redirect all pages to https successfully, but if I go to /wc-api/v2, it redirects me to /index.php.

```
# Custom Redirect 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wc-api/v2
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# End Custom Redirects 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

FYI The second block of redirects is required for Wordpress. I also cannot combine them into one single block or Wordpress will overwrite my changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When rewriting is configured in `.htaccess` context, after your last rule is applied, the whole process starts over again, using the internally rewritten URL as the new “input”, until no more rules match.

That means, when you request `/wc-api/v2`, it is not rewritten to HTTPS, because it fails your first `RewriteCond`, and so the rule in the next block rewrites it to `/index.php` internally.

Now the “next round” starts, with `/index.php` as input. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wc-api/v2` now does result in “true”, because the REQUEST_URI is not `/wc-api/v2` any more, it is now `/index.php`. Therefor, the `RewriteRule` is applied – and you are redirected to `https://example.com/index.php`

To avoid this, you must add another `RewriteCond`, which will prevent the rule from being applied for the REQUEST_URI `/index.php` as well:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wc-api/v2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an error on my server with the suggestion above so modified it slightly and found that this worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wc-api/v2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]


# BEGIN WordPress    
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Hope it works for you.